# How do I change the plot size in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, data-science

I have around 60 entities on the x-axis in ggplot geom_point, the labels are overlapping due to congested plot area. How do I make it large so that the labels are visible.
I am trying to plot year on the x-axis(from 1960 to 2020).

Comment: The actual solution is probably to ensure that the years are a numeric variable and not have a label for each year, which looks super-ugly anyway.

Comment: Yes the year is a numerical variable, int

Comment: You can change the "dimensions" of a plot by setting its width and/or height.  For this insert in the Rmd code chunk fig.width and/or fig.height to your liking. @SecurityObscurity sets the "default" width/height in your Rmd notebook. If you save out the ggplot, `ggsave()` has width and height parameter as well. Alternatively, you can work with different label (font)sizes or put them vertically. Last but not least you can influence the complete visualisation (and size dimensions of text) by increasing the resolution (e.g. setting dpi = 320). Worst case, do 2 visualisations.

Comment: Ray, can you please elaborate.
I don't want to save the plot, juts want to view it as of now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your notebook

```
options(repr.plot.width=15, repr.plot.height=8)
```

*Next time please keep in mind that you should provide a sample of what you have already tried*

Comment: Its my first question here, I apologize.
Thank you.

I tried the above code snippet but nothing happened.